# Создание пользователя в Google Workspace

Tags: python

Как можно создать пользователей Google Workspace с помощью скрипта?

Желательно на python.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте готовые утилиты, которые сократят и время и нервы. Очевидно, что одна из лучших в своем роде - это [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)

После установки

```
$> gam create user ai firstname Alex lastname Ivanov password "laJdhjwew45$DF"
```

Командно совместимый инструмент [GAMADV-XTD3](https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3) и набор скриптов [GAM-Scripts3](https://github.com/taers232c/GAM-Scripts3), большинство из которых будут работать и с [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)